How to convert an ECDSA public key (ECPublicKey) to OpenSSH format?
How do I convert a java.security.interfaces.ECPublicKey to OpenSSH string representation for use with ssh?
For example, given an ECPublicKey I want to get back a string like this: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBEAFuExXweUtKN3KYzoV+6eEyVfN9CLyM48FO2B9bZQ51bLtQvVo1MNVCXuW73dD2CgHXPryEwsTMyUR74GHN50= user@example.com

@PresidentJamesK.Polk I don't understand your question. The input is a ECDSA public key. I did not specify the curve type, but I don't think that is relevant to the question. What other information are you missing?

@PresidentJamesK.Polk I've updated the question. Let me know if this clarification helps.

Answering my own question...
You only need the toOpenSshPublicKey() function defined below. However, I've also included some related functions that you might useful:

Loading a private key from a file.
Converting a private key to a public key.
Generating the fingerprint of a public key.

Code
import com.github.cowwoc.pouch.core.WrappedCheckedException;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.PrivateKeyInfo;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x9.ECNamedCurveTable;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x9.X9ECParameters;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.AsymmetricKeyParameter;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.ECDomainParameters;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.ECPublicKeyParameters;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.util.OpenSSHPublicKeyUtil;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.spec.ECNamedCurveSpec;
import org.bouncycastle.math.ec.ECCurve;
import org.bouncycastle.math.ec.ECPoint;
import org.bouncycastle.math.ec.FixedPointCombMultiplier;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMKeyPair;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMParser;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JcaPEMKeyConverter;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.interfaces.ECPrivateKey;
import java.security.interfaces.ECPublicKey;
import java.security.spec.ECParameterSpec;
import java.security.spec.ECPublicKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.StringJoiner;

import static com.github.cowwoc.requirements10.java.DefaultJavaValidators.requireThat;
import static org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME;

/**
 * SSH helper functions.
 */
public class SshKeys
{
    private final JcaPEMKeyConverter pemToJca = new JcaPEMKeyConverter();

    /**
     * Creates a new instance.
     */
    public SshKeys()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Loads a {@code PrivateKey} from a file.
     *
     * @param path the path of the private key file
     * @return the {@code PrivateKey}
     * @throws IOException if the file does not contain a valid {@code PrivateKey}
     */
    public PrivateKey loadPrivateKey(Path path) throws IOException
    {
        try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path);
             PEMParser parser = new PEMParser(reader))
        {
            Object keyPair = parser.readObject();
            return switch (keyPair)
            {
                // Based on https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/b048c864157376fdaa1a889588ce1dea08629d7a/mail/src/test/java/org/bouncycastle/mail/smime/test/MailGeneralTest.java#L281
                case PEMKeyPair pem -> pemToJca.getPrivateKey(pem.getPrivateKeyInfo());
                // Based on https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/b048c864157376fdaa1a889588ce1dea08629d7a/mail/src/test/java/org/bouncycastle/mail/smime/test/MailGeneralTest.java#L407
                case PrivateKeyInfo pki -> pemToJca.getPrivateKey(pki);
                default -> throw new ClassCastException(keyPair.getClass().getName());
            };
        }
    }

    /**
     * Converts a private key to a public key, if possible.
     *
     * @param privateKey the private key
     * @return the public key
     */
    public PublicKey convertToPublicKey(PrivateKey privateKey)
    {
        // Get the key factory based on the private key algorithm
        try
        {
            KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(privateKey.getAlgorithm(), PROVIDER_NAME);
            return switch (privateKey)
            {
                case ECPrivateKey ecPrivateKey ->
                {
                    // Based on https://github.com/aergoio/heraj/blob/0bcea46c46429c320da711632624605a6225d20f/core/util/src/main/java/hera/util/pki/ECDSAKeyGenerator.java#L173
                    // and https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/efe1f511d8c58978af38e45215a7b7bf6477a10c/pkix/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/eac/jcajce/JcaPublicKeyConverter.java#L83
                    ECParameterSpec params = ecPrivateKey.getParams();

                    // Find the curve name from the private key parameters
                    String curveName = ((ECNamedCurveSpec) params).getName();
                    X9ECParameters x9Params = ECNamedCurveTable.getByName(curveName);
                    ECDomainParameters domainParams = new ECDomainParameters(
                        x9Params.getCurve(),
                        x9Params.getG(),
                        x9Params.getN(),
                        x9Params.getH(),
                        x9Params.getSeed()
                    );

                    BigInteger d = ecPrivateKey.getS();
                    ECPoint Q = new FixedPointCombMultiplier().multiply(domainParams.getG(), d).normalize();

                    // Create ECPublicKeySpec
                    ECPublicKeySpec spec = new ECPublicKeySpec(
                        new java.security.spec.ECPoint(Q.getAffineXCoord().toBigInteger(),
                            Q.getAffineYCoord().toBigInteger()), params
                    );

                    yield keyFactory.generatePublic(spec);
                }
                default -> throw new ClassCastException(privateKey.getClass().getName());
            };
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException | InvalidKeySpecException e)
        {
            throw WrappedCheckedException.wrap(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the OpenSSH representation of a public key.
     *
     * @param publicKey the public key
     * @param comment   the comment to append to the end of the key
     * @return the OpenSSH representation of the public key
     */
    public String toOpenSshPublicKey(PublicKey publicKey, String comment)
    {
        return switch (publicKey)
        {
            case ECPublicKey ecPublicKey -> toOpenSshPublicKey(ecPublicKey, comment);
            default -> throw new ClassCastException(publicKey.getClass().getName());
        };
    }

    /**
     * @param publicKey a public key
     * @return the OpenSSH fingerprint of the key
     * @throws NullPointerException if {@code publicKey} is null
     */
    public String toOpenSshFingerprint(PublicKey publicKey)
    {
        return switch (publicKey)
        {
            case ECPublicKey ecPublicKey -> toOpenSshFingerprint(ecPublicKey);
            default -> throw new ClassCastException(publicKey.getClass().getName());
        };
    }

    /**
     * @param publicKey a public key
     * @return the OpenSSH fingerprint of the key
     * @throws NullPointerException if {@code publicKey} is null
     */
    public String toOpenSshFingerprint(ECPublicKey publicKey)
    {
        String opensshPublicKey = toOpenSshPublicKey(publicKey, "");

        // Extract the base64 part of the OpenSSH public key
        String base64Key = opensshPublicKey.split(" ")[1];
        byte[] keyBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64Key);

        // Compute the SHA-256 fingerprint
        MessageDigest md;
        try
        {
            md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
        {
            // This is a deployment-time decision. Either the JVM supports this digest type or it doesn't.
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
        byte[] fingerprint = md.digest(keyBytes);

        StringJoiner hexFingerprint = new StringJoiner(":");
        for (byte b : fingerprint)
            hexFingerprint.add(String.format("%02x", b));
        return hexFingerprint.toString();
    }

    /**
     * @param publicKey the public key
     * @param comment   the comment to append to the end of the key
     * @return the OpenSSH representation of the key
     * @throws NullPointerException if any of the arguments are null
     */
    public String toOpenSshPublicKey(ECPublicKey publicKey, String comment)
    {
        requireThat(comment, "comment").isNotNull();
        AsymmetricKeyParameter param = getAsymmetricKeyParameter(publicKey);

        // Encode the public key in OpenSSH format
        byte[] encodedPublicKey;
        try
        {
            encodedPublicKey = OpenSSHPublicKeyUtil.encodePublicKey(param);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // The exception is declared but never actually thrown by the method
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }

        // Determine the SSH key type based on the curve name
        String sshKeyType = getSshKeyType(publicKey);
        return sshKeyType + " " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encodedPublicKey) + " " + comment;
    }

    /**
     * @param publicKey a public key
     * @return the asymmetric key parameters of the key
     * @throws NullPointerException if {@code publicKey} is null
     */
    private AsymmetricKeyParameter getAsymmetricKeyParameter(ECPublicKey publicKey)
    {
        // Retrieve the curve parameters from the named curve
        X9ECParameters ecParams = ECNamedCurveTable.getByName(getCurveName(publicKey));
        ECCurve curve = ecParams.getCurve();
        ECPoint g = ecParams.getG();
        BigInteger n = ecParams.getN();
        BigInteger h = ecParams.getH();

        // Convert java.security.spec.ECPoint to BouncyCastle ECPoint
        java.security.spec.ECPoint w = publicKey.getW();
        ECPoint q = curve.createPoint(w.getAffineX(), w.getAffineY());

        ECDomainParameters domainParams = new ECDomainParameters(curve, g, n, h);
        return new ECPublicKeyParameters(q, domainParams);
    }

    /**
     * @param publicKey a public key
     * @return the name of the elliptic curve used in the public key
     * @throws NullPointerException if {@code publicKey} is null
     */
    private String getCurveName(ECPublicKey publicKey)
    {
        ECNamedCurveSpec params = (ECNamedCurveSpec) publicKey.getParams();
        return params.getName();
    }

    /**
     * @param publicKey a public key
     * @return the SSH type of the public key
     * @throws NullPointerException if {@code publicKey} is null
     */
    private String getSshKeyType(ECPublicKey publicKey)
    {
        String curveName = getCurveName(publicKey);
        // SSH key prefix: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5656#section-6.2
        return "ecdsa-sha2-" + switch (curveName)
        {
            // Mapping from curve type to SSH key type: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5656#section-10.1
            // Equivalent curves: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4492.html#page-32
            case "secp256r1", "prime256v1" -> "nistp256";
            case "secp384r1" -> "nistp384";
            case "secp521r1" -> "nistp521";
            default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid curve type: " + publicKey);
        };
    }
}


Private key? The question only asked about a public key.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk Yes, I know. I provided related functions as a bonus. They are not strictly required to answer the question.
